# Springboot test fails to run

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotest

I'm trying to run an integration test using kotest and running in to the below error. The tests run fine if I only run a single test but it fails when I try to run all tests in the class.

```
Failed to find merged annotation for @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find merged annotation for @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
```

HelloTest.kt

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [DemoApplication::class])
class HelloTest: FunSpec() {

    override fun extensions() = listOf(SpringExtension)

    init{
        test("should..."){
            ...
        }
        
        test("should..."){
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you have an issue with conflicting dependencies. Can you post your `mvn dependency:tree` output? Or `gradle dependencies`, if you use gradle.

Comment: Also please include your imports. There's a SpringExtension for JUnit included with Spring, I sometimes get them mixed up when importing and using the wrong one could also lead to problems